# google sheets calculates using old formula

Tags: google-sheets, ref

[Screenshot of problem formula and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E15Rj.png) Several of my sheets have been throwing #REF errors based on previous contents of the cell. I change the name of a range or sheet, edit a formula to use the new name, but get a #REF error saying the **previous** sheet/range name can't be resolved. [(
Here's a sheet showing the problem)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vH-V57_NFabfcI71tS7QaIgW5Pd_CF600_kD4HCA2ps/edit?usp=sharing)

Example: below, cell P19 contains the formula **=I1+'1 Oct 16'!P19**, but returns the #REF error with message "**Unresolved sheet name '1 Sep 16'**" — the sheet has been renamed, and the formula has been edited to use the new name, but the calculation fails because it's still using the old name. I've had the same trouble in a lot of sheets.

Sometimes changing the formula to something else entirely, and then manually re-entering what I want, will clear the problem up. In the example sheet, though, no matter where I enter the formula now in P19, I get the same error. This happens in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I'm running OS X 10.11.6 on an early-2014 MacBook Air, Intel Core i5 1400 MHz processor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the formulae themselves, they are working they are showing the results of the previous cells which are also reference errors.
The original error is in `1 Oct 16` which is trying to reference `1 Sep 16!P21`, that sheet doesn't exist and needs some replacement.

Comment: _That_ is seriously embarrassing! How could I forget to check the input values? But many thanks: I was stumped.